# How to specify the Streamwriter path location

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I wanted to write a text to file using StreamWriter.But Filename should be current date name.
here is my coding.Can somebody tell me how to specify the file creation path?

Code Edit :
In here i wanted to create a .txt file but in here file not created.

```
public void WriteToFile( string name, string source, int dest, string messageIn, string operatorNew)
{
   string directory = ResolveUrl("~/DesktopModules/SMSFunction/SMSText");
   string filename = String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}__{1}", DateTime.Now,name);
   string path = Path.Combine(directory, filename);

   if (!File.Exists(filename))
   {

       using (StreamWriter str = File.CreateText(path))
       {
           str.WriteLine("msisdn: " + source);
           str.WriteLine("shortcode : " + dest);
           str.WriteLine("Message : " + messageIn);
           str.WriteLine("Operator :" + operatorNew);
           str.Flush();

       }
   }
   else if (File.Exists(filename))
   {

       using (var str = new StreamWriter(filename)) 

       {
           str.WriteLine("msisdn: " + source);
           str.WriteLine("shortcode : " + dest);
           str.WriteLine("Message : " + messageIn);
           str.WriteLine("Operator :" + operatorNew);
           str.Flush();
       }

   }
```

Comment: you are not providing any file extension, add `.txt` to filename

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to make following changes

1.Replace `ResolveUrl` with `Server.MapPath`

```
string directory = Server.MapPath("~/DesktopModules/SMSFunction/SMSText");
```

2.Add the file extension `.txt` as shown below

```
string filename = String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}__{1}.txt", DateTime.Now,name);
```

3.when you are checking whether file exists or not provide the path of the file , instead of filename

```
File.Exists(path);
```

4.under the `else if` block , here also provide the path , instead of filename

```
var str = new StreamWriter(path));
```

putting all together the code looks like,

```
 string directory = Server.MapPath("~/DesktopModules/SMSFunction/SMSText");
 string filename = String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}__{1}.txt", DateTime.Now, name);
 string path = Path.Combine(directory, filename);

    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        using (StreamWriter str = File.CreateText(path))
        {
            str.WriteLine("msisdn: " + source);
            str.WriteLine("shortcode : " + dest);
            str.WriteLine("Message : " + messageIn);
            str.WriteLine("Operator :" + operatorNew);
            str.Flush();
        }
    }
    else if (File.Exists(path))
    {
        using (var str = new StreamWriter(path))
        {
            str.WriteLine("msisdn: " + source);
            str.WriteLine("shortcode : " + dest);
            str.WriteLine("Message : " + messageIn);
            str.WriteLine("Operator :" + operatorNew);
            str.Flush();
     }
```

Comment: @NimanthaPrasad i hope you understood why those changes were needed.

Comment: Can we remove name from here ? i think it's unused string filename = String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}__{1}.txt", DateTime.Now,name);

Comment: @NimanthaPrasad its useful the filename would be `2012-08-20__xyz.txt` where `name = xyz`. so its totally depends upon your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

`File.Create` returns `FileStream`, and you need `StreamWriter`. You'll have to use its constructor that accepts `Stream`:

```
using (var str = new StreamWriter(File.CreateText(path)))
```

Comment: I want If file already exist then need to write or if not create it and write

Comment: Have you tried `File.Open`? Or different `FileStream` constructors?

Comment: I asked about `File.Open` and `FileStream`. You updated code has neither.

Comment: C# beginner have problem, FileStream mean StreamWriter or StreamReader?

Comment: @NimanthaPrasad `FileStream` means [FileStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Simplify, use FileStream to create or overwrite your file (see below) depending on your neeeds you might want to change the [FileMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode.aspx) to be something else (Append ?)

```
public void WriteToFile(string name, string source, int dest, string messageIn, string operatorNew)
{
    string directory = ResolveUrl("~/DesktopModules/SMSFunction/SMSText");
    string filename = String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}__{1}", DateTime.Now,name);
    string path = Path.Combine(directory, filename);

    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
    {
        using (StreamWriter str = new StreamWriter(fs))
        {
            str.WriteLine("msisdn: " + source);
            str.WriteLine("shortcode : " + dest);
            str.WriteLine("Message : " + messageIn);
            str.WriteLine("Operator :" + operatorNew);
            str.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your console app project name is DataPrep. Now you can write in Data directory location by creating a new file namely as db.json

```
string filePath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"..\..\..\")) + @"Data\db.json";
            if (!File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                using (StreamWriter _streamWriter = File.CreateText(filePath))
                {
                    _streamWriter.Write(resultAll);
                    _streamWriter.Flush();
                }
            }
            else if (File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                using (var _streamWriter = new StreamWriter(filePath))
                {
                    _streamWriter.Write(resultAll);
                    _streamWriter.Flush();
                }

            }
```