# how to write a file to Local Document library

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, streamwriter

i am using streamwriter to write the file, however the location of the new written  file is located within one of the folder with in the project folder but i would like the location to be on the document library of the computer. im using a mvc application not a console Application

Any help would be appreciate.

thank you

```
using (var File = new StreamWriter(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/OutputFileTest.csv"), false)) // true for appending the file and false to overwrite the file
            {
                foreach (var item in outputFile)
                {
                    File.WriteLine(item);
                }
            }
```

Comment: I think you're looking for this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: using (var File = new StreamWriter(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "/OutputFileTest.csv", false)) // true for appending the file and false to overwrite the file
            {
                foreach (var item in outputFile)
                {
                    File.WriteLine(item);
                }
            }

Comment: after using your code i get an error of " System Environment does contain a definition of special folder"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to specify the Streamwriter path location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12003110/how-to-specify-the-streamwriter-path-location)

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN:

```
// Sample for the Environment.GetFolderPath method
using System;

class Sample 
{
public static void Main() 
{
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("GetFolderPath: {0}", 
             Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments));
}
}
/*
This example produces the following results:

    */
```